# How to force addition using meta_table in lua?

Tags: function, lua, arguments, addition, metatable

I have defined addition using metatable as follows.

```
local matrix_meta = {}
matrix_meta.__add = function( ... )
    return matrix.add( ... )
end
```

I want to add variables using matrix_meta add.  The following commands work well.

```
matrix(p)+q    
matrix(p)+matrix(q)
p+matrix(q)
```

However the following code doesn't work.

```
p+q
```

The reason is obvious that it doesn't recognize `p` or `q` as matrix objects. It simply throws error that trying to perform arithmetic on table values. I am curious about how to force addition for matrix objects. I mean that is it possible to execute in lua something like this `env-Matrix: p+q`  or as `matrix_meta.__add: p,q` so that `p` and `q` are auto recognized as matrix objects. So the problem is to perform addition in matrix environment where variables will be recognized as matrix objects. Note that I simply don't want to this only for two variables, there may be more than two variables.

Comment: what are p and q? what is matrix()?  why should Lua "recognize p or q as matrix objects"? where did you define that?  please add more info

Comment: `local p={{2,4,6},{8,10,12},{14,16,20}}` `local q={{1,2,3},{8,10,12},{14,16,20}}` other related terminology is in this lua file https://github.com/davidm/lua-matrix/blob/master/lua/matrix.lua

Comment: The best way would be to write an `matrixAdd` function that assumes both arguments are matrixes. Otherwise, you need some way to distinguish matrixes from other tables. Also, it's impossible to overload operators like you're doing without metatables.

Comment: @luther matrix.add already assumes both arguments are matrices.  All commands like matrix.add(p,q), matrix.add(matrix(p), matrix(q)), matrix.add(p,matrix(q)) etc. work without error. The basic problem is that matrix_meta add (+) doesn't recognize that p and q are matrices. It treats as table. I just want to add some environment so that usual addition + will be matrix_meta addition.

Comment: Please take a look at this question and the answer as well, it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670985/luahow-to-create-a-custom-method-on-all-tables

Comment: So you want to do this without a function or a metatable. Even if that were possible, that would mean overloading operators globally. Then we'd be screwed whenever we import two modules that overload the same operators.

Answer (score 2):

As defined in your comment

```
local p={{2,4,6},{8,10,12},{14,16,20}}
local q={{1,2,3},{8,10,12},{14,16,20}}
```

So unless you something like

```
local p = setmetatable(p={{2,4,6},{8,10,12},{14,16,20}}, matrix_meta)
```

`p` and `q` are just regular Lua tables with no metamethods.

Arithmetic operations are not defined for Lua tables. Hence the error message.

If you don't like the Lua operators or its syntax, consider using another programming language.

It wouldn't hurt to write something like `m({2,4,6},{8,10,12},{14,16,20})` instead of `{{2,4,6},{8,10,12},{14,16,20}}`.

Comment: I am seeking a solution where everywhere I don't have to write `m({2,4,6},{8,10,12},{14,16,20})`. Just an environment where tables are treated as matrices. Note that `matrix.add` already assumes both arguments are matrices. All commands like `matrix.add(p,q)`, `matrix.add(matrix(p), matrix(q))`, `matrix.add(p,matrix(q))` etc. work without error.

Comment: @Maths89 yes because matrix.add implements that for standard tables. If Lua would already know that, you would not need matrix.add in the first place. At some point you have to draw a line between the programming language and the program.